# Adding suffix and prefix to WooCommerce order number without using a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I want to add a suffix and a prefix to a Woo Commerce order number without using a plugin.

I tried to use this hook which is not working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number','my_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2);

function my_woocommerce_order_number( $oldnumber, $order ) {    
    return 'VC'.$order->id;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2);

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    $prefix = '#SAM-';
    $suffix = '-' . date(Y); 
    // You can use either one of $order->id (or) $order_id
    // Both will work
    return $prefix . $order->id . $suffix;
}
```

Refernce: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#379

Comment: Here is a classic example.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-order-number-woo/