# How can I add the customer username to the WooCommerce Order Number?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am running Woo Commerce and need to add the customers 'username' and date to the order ID so that instead of the order ID being #10, it becomes #Cafe101-15-01-2020.

username: Cafe101
date: 15-01-2020 (15th Jan 2020)

I have come across some code to add the date so need some help to add the username.

**Reference:** [Adding suffix and prefix to WooCommerce order number without using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783349/adding-suffix-and-prefix-to-woocommerce-order-number-without-using-a-plugin)

Comment: Do users have to register to purchase?

Comment: Any feed back on the answer will be appreciated please, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That might be what you are looking for:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'custom_order_number', 1, 2 );
function custom_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Order creation date
    $date = $order->get_date_created();
    $date = $date->date('d-m-Y');

    // Customer username
    $user = $order->get_user();
    $username = $user->user_login;

    return '#' . $username . '-' . $date;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Reference: [Available methods from WC_Abstract_Order Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html)